# My question was closed as a duplicate, I found the answer at the link given, now what do I do?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

When my question was closed for being a duplicate, I went to the link given and went through the answers offered (over 30 of them). One of them solved the problem.

There's no place for me to answer my closed duplicate question. So now, I'm not sure what to do.

I guess having the question on the site would be redundant in a way, but it might also be helpful to others like me who are beginners at C++ and may focus primarily on the language syntax and logic. I was surprised at the solution to my problem. My code turned out to be perfect. The problem came from the IDE.

So what should I do?

Comment: Nothing, that's what's supposed to happen. You had a problem, you were pointed to some answers, one solved your problem; job done!

Comment: *"went through the answers offered (over 30 of them). One of them solved the problem."* - Good job!, lots of users give up and just say that the linked duplicate doesn't solve their problem. So kudos for actually reading through them and finding the issue.

Comment: Maybe vote up the helpful answer, otherwise that's it.

Comment: you can add a comment under your question referring to answer that helped you most, to save time for future readers who could get straight to it based on your comment

Comment: Note that your question wasn't "blocked". It was closed, which doesn't mean anything other than the fact that people can't answer it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions.

Answer (score 21):

Your question was *closed* as a duplicate so it can't be answered any longer.

From [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

> The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.

This saves you and potential answerers the time of finding or formulating an answer. Your duplicate can now act as a *signpost* to the duplicate target, eg. if it contains new useful search terms.

There's not much you need to do now, but some useful suggestions from the comments:

- Consider upvoting the helpful answer ([comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404427/my-question-was-blocked-for-duplicate-i-found-the-answer-at-the-link-given-now#comment818998_404427) by [Robert Longson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson))
- Consider adding a comment to your question explaining which answer helped you the most ([comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404427/my-question-was-blocked-for-duplicate-i-found-the-answer-at-the-link-given-now#comment818999_404427) by [gnat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/839601/gnat))

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to answer it because it's already been answered.  The duplicate answered your question, so as long as your question is still visible on the site, there is a good chance that someone who also sees your question will have it answered by the duplicate.

Answer (score 9):

Not much as others have said, but you could take a moment to reflect, maybe. This is me lecturing a little so feel free to completely disregard if I'm telling you nothing new. What I am about to explain might help someone else instead.

The primary use of Stack Overflow, a knowledge base, is to find answers to questions by *searching* for them - asking a new question is a last resort. This is in your own interest too because asking (good) questions takes a bloody large amount of time and effort - plus it can take ages before someone actually answers correctly. Finding existing answers is really the goal that should be on everyone's mind. How to search is a skill though, and like other skills it is one that takes practice to master.

Let's take your question, you didn't link to it but I can see in your profile your latest C++ question is closed as a duplicate and that duplicate has a ton of answers as per the description. It is in my opinion a by the books question that includes the error output - well done. Maybe you did not need to post all that code but if you are unsure what to leave out then it is better to have too much than too little I say. The error is thus, if I scrape off the fluff:

> undefined reference to `Child_Director::Child_Director(Child_Module*)

So, I put

```
c++ undefined reference
```

into Google. Use whatever search engine you prefer of course. Let me break down how I got to that specific search query:

- I take a generic part of the error which does not contain data specific to you like a classname or a filename
- I add context to it, the programming language in this case

The first hit I get is this Stack Overflow post:

[C++ error 'Undefined reference to Class::Function()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712821/c-error-undefined-reference-to-classfunction)

Your mileage may vary a little because Google does not return the exact same search results for everyone. Now that is a different question than the one your question is closed as a duplicate of... but it itself is also closed as a duplicate, and guess where the duplicate link takes you.

Of course I'm cheating here because I knew where I wanted to end up, but all I had to do is take a few keywords from the error output you got, add a little context to it and a world of very relevant information was presented to me in almost no time at all - on Stack Overflow, I didn't even look at any other links that were returned. You *should* be able to get there before you have to ask anything which judging by the question took you some time to type up. Good job, but... ultimately the time could have been better spent.

---

Normally it is preferred to use an external search engine, but for the heck of it put `c++ undefined reference` into the stackoverflow.com search bar at the top of the page and see what you get. The top link for me was very familiar. Sometimes the site search actually works to find answers.

Comment: You could add that one can add 'site:stackoverflow.com' to a google search when wanting to limit it to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Indeed, but I would not ignore the rest of the web just yet :)